# Why we use android:allowTaskReparenting of an activity?

Tags: android

I searched following website for the  exact answer of this question
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0204853497e7b7f8 , http://android.bigresource.com/Android-allowTaskReparenting-and-FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP-conflict-IBF9JKWuO.html and android developer documents.

But I didn't understand it completely.

Comment: did you check, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html this has a section under task reparenting with example

Comment: hi nandeesh your link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the activity can move from the task it starts to the task it has an affinity for, when that task comes to the foreground.

For example, suppose that an activity that reports weather conditions in selected cities is defined as part of a travel app. It has the same affinity as other activities in the same app (the default app affinity) and it allows re-parenting with this attribute. When one of your activities starts the weather reporter activity, it initially belongs to the same task as your activity. However, when the travel app's task comes to the foreground, the weather reporter activity is reassigned to that task and displayed within it.